# Use angular route params without subscribing to it

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-ui-router

I am writing a simple UI application and I need to call API to get the product by id in a product-details component. Id I get from route params

Usually, I do something like this:

```js
this.activatedRoute.params
   .subscribe(params => {
     if (params['primaryKey']) {
       this.service.get(params['primaryKey'])
         .subscribe(product => {
           this.product = product;
         });
     }
   });
```

And it works fine just looks a little bit ugly with these trees of subscribing. I wanna use more RxJS so it will look like this (console logs are just for demonstration):

```js
this.product$ = this.activatedRoute.params
  .pipe(filter(params => {
       console.log('in filter', params);
       return 'primaryKey' in params;
     }),
     map(params => {
       console.log('in map', params);
       return parseInt(params.primaryKey, 10);
     }),
     switchMap(primaryKey => {
       console.log('in switch map', primaryKey);
       return this.service.get(primaryKey);
     }));
```

But it doesn't work this way until I subscribe to it in the end (it even doesn't trigger any of console logs)... why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You start with an Observable, which then you pass through some functions (filtering, mapping, and so on).

However, you will not start observing it and collecting values until you call `subscribe()`. You can move all logic to inside that function or extract it to RxJS operators, but you still that function at the end:

```
this.product$ = this.activatedRoute.params
  .pipe(...)
  .subscribe();
```

You can find more in the documentation on the [subscribe function](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/guide/observable#subscribing-to-observables).

Comment: but this way it returns me not Observable but Subscription in my product$ variable, and it isn't what I want. As I mentioned above in reply to another comment my approach works fine with Observables created by HTTP requests (e. g. I don't need to subscribe to them to observe them), but with ActiveRoute params I've stuck...

Comment: Can you explain what you do next with `product$`? Of course you must assign `this.product = product` somewhere inside that `pipe()` or `subscribe()` methods to have the same usage as previously.

Answer (score 7):

#### Solution without subscribing

You can get the parameters of the route by using:

```
this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id')
```

`route` is of type `ActivatedRoute`

```
  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
  ) { }
```

Comment: If this doesn't  work for you, try `this.route.snapshot.queryParamMap.get(''id')`;

Answer (score 0):

You need to subscribe at the end if you want to get value from stream you've created. It won't work until you do this. Other way is to use an async pipe in your template on product$.

Comment: but in my products list component, for example, I have `this.products$ = this.service.get();` (in service: `get = (): Observable<ProductModel[]> => this.http.get<ProductModel[]>('some-api-path')`) and it works like a charm without sibscribing to it

Comment: I think it is because of async pipe in your component html file, there is no option to read data from stream when you're not subscribing to it.

Comment: Does async pipe subscribe to stream? How can I use it outside of arrays just with a single object? Something kinda `<div *ngIf="(hero | async)">` doesn't work and to write `<div>{{(hero | async)?.name}}</div>` for each object property is a little bit creepy. I do can subscribe and  deal with it, but if there is a way not to store data outside of streams at all it will be perfect

Answer (score 0):

With applying various of operators using `pipe` you create new `Observable` based on existing one, saying that additional functions must be applied on emitted results.

However it doesn't emit values till first `Subscription` is created.

Comment: As I mentioned above in reply to another comment my approach works fine with Observables created by HTTP requests (e. g. I don't need to subscribe to them to observe them), but with ActiveRoute params I've stuck...

Answer (score 0):

One of the possible solutions could be

```
this.route.queryParams.<QUERY_PARAM>
```

`route` must be of type `ActivatedRouteSnapshot`